# Killing child process one by one

Tags: c, unix, signals, posix, handler

First, I create the multiple number of child process using the for loop. Then, I put all of the child process into sleep(by adding infinite sleep block).

```
void kill_child(int sig);

int main(void){
     signal(SIGHUP, kill_child);
     for(int i = 0; i < max_child; i++){
        pid_t id = fork();
        if(id == 0){
            printf("Hi, i am a child\n");
            while(1){sleep(1);}
        }
        if(id == 1){
            printf("Hi, i am a parent\n");
       
        }
     }
     
}

void kill_child(int sig){
     if(sig==SIGHUP){
         //do stuff to kill single child
     }
}
```

What am I planning to do next, send the kill -HUP parent from terminal to kill the child process one by one. At the end, if no child process terminate the program.

I just want to know is there any way to kill single child at a time under condition like this.

Comment: The pid returned by `fork()` is extremely unlikely to ever be 1...

Comment: @Shawn oh then is it better way using if(who > 0) instead of if(who == 1)??

Comment: Yup. And don't forget to handle the error case when it returns a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you can use an array with global scope to safe children's pid and then use it into the function kill_child calling:  int kill(pid_t pid, int sig).
Inside kill_child, I think you can send SIGKILL to children or redefine behavior with signal function if you want to send SIGTERM.
This can be a solution.
Aniway, I noticed something that can be improved (in my humble opinion) in your code:

1. I'm not sure that your program will print "Hi, i am a parent\n" because you can't be sure that at least one child has pid = 1(unless you are sure of it for other reasons)
2. The while loop create a lot of overhead because every second you reactivate a process and this process sooner or later take the CPU only for call sleep to wait one second

I hope I have helped you!

Comment: oh i might consider trying that way. I totally ignoring it because, unlike thread they are not sharing memory.

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
int main(void){
     signal(SIGHUP, kill_child);
     for(int i = 0; i < max_child; i++){
        pid_t id = fork();
        if(id == 0){
            printf("Hi, i am a child\n");
            while(1){sleep(1);}
        }
        if(id == 1){
```

where do you get that `id == 1` when `fork()` returns to the parent?  That's never true.  For that you have had to `fork()` the `init` process, and that's never true for a user process.  The kernel returns the pid (and this is why you call it `id`) of the child process to the parent, so you never get into the following piece of code.

```
            printf("Hi, i am a parent\n");
       
        }
     }
     
}
```

You need to arrange an array (as told you in another answer) and save all the pids of all the processes you have forked.  Instead of the `printf()` above, just do the following.

### kc.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_CHILDREN 10

pid_t chld_pids[MAX_CHILDREN];
size_t chld_pids_sz = 0;

void kill_children(int sig, int delay);
void signal_handler(int sig);

int main()
{
    while (chld_pids_sz < MAX_CHILDREN) {
        pid_t chld_id = fork();
        if (chld_id < 0) { /* error in fork() */
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Error in fork: %s (errno == %d)\n",
                    strerror(errno), errno);
            kill_children(SIGHUP, 0); /* kill all children with
                                       * no delay */
            break; /* stop processing */
        } else if (chld_id == 0) { /* child */
            /* avoid signal SIGHUP so no child is killed when the
             * process group leader is killed.  This is sent
             * automatically by the kernel to end a job. */
            signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
            for(;;) {
                /* print our pid on stdout each second to
                 * indicate we are alive. */
                printf("[%d]", getpid());
                fflush(stdout); /* force buffer flush */
                sleep(1);
            }
            /* NOTREACHED */
        } else { /* parent */
            printf("Parent: started child %d\n", chld_id);
            chld_pids[chld_pids_sz++] = chld_id;
        }
    }
    signal(SIGHUP, signal_handler);
    /* now we wait for all children to finish, no need to know
     * the pids, as we are waiting until wait(2) returns an error
     * (no children to wait for) */
    int chld_id, status;
    while ((chld_id = wait(&status)) >= 0) {
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("Child %d exited with status %d\n",
                    chld_id, WEXITSTATUS(status));
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("Child %d was killed with signal %d\n",
                    chld_id, WTERMSIG(status));
            if (WCOREDUMP(status)) {
                printf("Child %d dumped a core file\n",
                    chld_id);
            }
        }
    }
} /* main */

void kill_children(int sig, int delay)
{
    printf("kill_children: Using delay %d\n", delay);
    for (int i = 0; i < chld_pids_sz; ++i) {
        if (delay > 0) { /* only sleep if delay > 0 */
            sleep(delay);
        }
        printf("Killing pid=%d\n", chld_pids[i]);
        int res = kill(chld_pids[i], sig);
        if (res < 0) {
            printf("Error killing pid %d: %s (errno = %d)\n",
                    chld_pids[i], strerror(errno), errno);
        }
    }
}

void signal_handler(int unused)
{
    kill_children(SIGINT, 3);
}
```

a copy of this code is published [here](https://github.com/mojadita/so/tree/master/c/kill_children) iif you want to download it and follow the versioning of it.